# Is there any ranking neural network especially in R?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I know there are many neural network for classification and regression problems. I myself use **caret** package in R for those problem. But now I am looking for a neural network which can be used for ranking the prediction values.

For example consider the widely used [iris flower dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) which I myself used initially for my studies. The dataset has 50 samples of data for three species Iris setosa, Iris virginica and Iris versicolor. Currently we can train this data set using any classification algorithm and predict a absolute result

```
Sepal length    Sepal width Petal length    Petal width Predicted Species
5.1                  3.4        1.4             0.3     I. setosa
```

Instead of this absolute result I want a ranking with prediction accuracy with cut off (eg:>50% accuracy)

```
Ranking Predicted Species
   1     I. setosa(93%)
   2     I. virginica (64%) 
   3     I. versicolor (43%)
```

Can It be done using nerual network in R or any other machine learning system?

Comment: Your predicted species data doesn't sum to unity since 93+64+43>100. Perhaps you could clarify what "Confidence" you're looking for?

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Sorry for that. My thinking is that the model will predict like its is "93%" sure its setosa "64%" sure its virginica

Comment: How can that possibly mean anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probabilities are what are returned by default in the `nnet` package.  If you are using `caret` you can simply get the probabilities by using:

```
# caret predict
predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "prob")

# nnet predict (Note - this is the default 'type')
predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "raw")
```